# Windows 2012 R2 - DNS resolving to internal IP

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2012-r2, nameserver, domain-name, windows-dns

I'm currently working on my infrastructure and since now it was good.

I have a Windows 2012 R2 server on AWS, with a Elastic (Public) IP. I have 3 domain:

```
domain1.com -> point to a CPanel hosting, which is good
domain1.net -> using .info NS to use my DNS
domain1.info -> ns1 + ns2 point to my public IP
```

Right now, it works. The .net domain is resolved via my own DNS and this is good.

The problem is: when I try externally my .net domain, it points me to the private (internal) IP of my server, in this case 10.10.254.5. But externally this address is not accessible obviously.

I don't know if I need to put my public IP for every record in my DNS (which is also a Domain Controller with the domain (.net)) or make a magic trick that would point the dns correctly internally?

If you have suggestions, don't hesitate!

Comment: `I don't know if I need to put my public IP for every record in my DNS (which is also a Domain Controller with the domain (.net)` - My suggestion would be that you not host your public DNS zone on your DC/DNS server and don't expose this server to the internet.

Comment: Well, unfortunately, I don't have the right to discuss of that. Even if I agree with you. I need my DC to be the DNS for its own domain, this is the structure we want.